# Can a listener receive and send broadcast request?

Tags: c, network-programming, client-server

Any help/feedback would be appreciated. i would like to set a listener (server) such that it would receive data from a broadcaster client and then  it would send information over the same socket. Is this possible to do in C Programming if so how? 
EDIT: CODE ADDED

```
/* udpserver.c */ 

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sock;
    int addr_len, bytes_read;
    char recv_data[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr , client_addr;


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);


    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
        sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

printf("\nUDPServer Waiting for client on port 5000");
    fflush(stdout);

while (1)
{

      bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);


  recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';

      printf("\n(%s , %d) said : ",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),
                                   ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
      printf("%s", recv_data);
  fflush(stdout);

      /* HERE IS MY CODE ADDED */
      if (sendto(sockfd, "HELLO", 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len) == -1) {
    perror("talker: sendto");
    exit(1);
}
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are already bidirectional, meaning you can send and receive data with the same connection.
There is a good example of a TCP/UDP server and client in C [here](http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html)

Comment: hi Steve, im using the example from the site (udpserver.c) however, when add the function sendto() after receiving the message, it does not work. please see the code above to see what i add. thx

Answer (score 0):

Is the recvFrom working? Do you get the prints which you have after recvFrom()?

Comment: I wanted to know if you are blocked on receive by any chance.